# 2x2 anova as post hoc test following a 2x3 anova

Tags: anova, interaction, post-hoc

I did a 3x2 anova - my data looks like in the figure below[image]

I get significant main effects and a significant (3x2) interaction.

I now want to test the interaction between the blue and green bars. So something like a post-hoc 2x2 anova. This sounds weird though. So I have two (I think) simple questions:

1. How should I report it? I have good reasons to test the 2x2 interaction, but I can't really call it a planned comparison: it's not *quite* theory-driven.
2. Should I do any corrections? It would make no sense to test all possible interactions, but I could have also tested the interaction between red-green and red-blue. Should I then correct my critical values accordingly?

Comment: Since you don't have any a priori hypotheses, I would run a [Tukey HSD test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) for both main effects and the interaction effect. Then look at the output and report only those comparisons you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm interested in the 2x2 interaction, not in a simple comparison of means. I guess it wouldn't be appropriate to correct the F value with Tukey's correction, right?

Comment: OK, I don't really know where to start but your are confusing a lot of terms here. Pretty much everything in [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) is about comparing means, incl. [post-hoc tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_analysis), which are done after the ANOVA and when no a priori hypotheses were specified.The F-value is simply the signal to noise ratio - why would you want to adjust this? Have a look what having an [interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)#Interactions_in_ANOVA) means.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. I think we're just talking past each other. I'm not as lost as it may sound, I think it's pretty clear to me what an interaction is. I'll try to rephrase the question.